# How to make an Angular app witch Universal SSR use dynamic configurations from json file?

Tags: javascript, angular, kubernetes

I was assigned the task of making a dynamic load of settings for the Angular application from the JSON file on the server during the application start. The peculiarity is that the application uses server rendering with Universal.
I tried to do this for the browser using this method.
https://juristr.com/blog/2018/01/ng-app-runtime-config
But it works only for the browser app rendering.
How to do it for server-side rendering?

Comment: Hey! Welcome to Stackoverflow. Can you please include more information about the error you're getting on the server-side?

Answer (score 5):

The most likely culprit here is that you're loading json file from relative path but 
Universal does not currently support relative urls but only absolute.

So you can provide absolute path to your json file:

**server.ts**

```
app.engine('html', (_, options, callback) => {
  const protocol = options.req.protocol;
  const host = options.req.get('host');

  const engine = ngExpressEngine({
    bootstrap: AppServerModuleNgFactory,
    providers: [
      provideModuleMap(LAZY_MODULE_MAP),
      { provide: 'APP_BASE_URL', useFactory: () => `${protocol}://${host}`, deps: [] },
    ]
  });
  engine(_, options, callback);
});
```

**your.service.ts**

```
@Injectable()
export class ConfigProvider {
  config: Config;

  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient,
    @Inject(PLATFORM_ID) private platformId: {},
    @Inject('APP_BASE_URL') @Optional() private readonly baseUrl: string
  ) {
    if (isPlatformBrowser(platformId)) {
      this.baseUrl = document.location.origin;
    }
  }

  loadConfig() {
    return this.http.get<Config>(
      `${this.baseUrl}/assets/plugins-config.json`
    );
  }
}
```

For more details see [example of project](https://github.com/alexzuza/angular-plugin-architecture/blob/23ab862d96f2fe65942a8cd78ac605ff0f699f56/src/app/services/plugins-config.provider.ts#L32) that also uses APP_INITIALIZER to load config

Comment: I added the code from the example in the server.ts and my service files
but in the my service I do not get the value of the baseUrl = null

Comment: The value will be only available on the server side(nodejs). In browser we use `this.baseUrl = document.location.origin` here.

Comment: Thank you very much. Your advice helped me solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following package

https://www.npmjs.com/package/runtime-config-loader

Answer (score 0):

This is what I use and works just fine...

```
constructor(@Inject(DOCUMENT) private document: Document,
           @Inject(PLATFORM_ID) private platformId: Object,
           @Optional() @Inject(REQUEST) private request: any) {
    if (isPlatformServer(platformId)) {
       const port = request.socket.localPort;
       this.baseUrl = this.request.protocol + '://' + this.request.hostname + ':' + port;
    } else {
       this.baseUrl = this.document.location.origin;
    }
    ....
}
```