# How to set multiregional subdirectories in angular 8 + expressjs

Tags: angular, express, server-side-rendering, angular-universal

We struggle to understand how to set in angular8 a multiregional subdirectory. We cannot find a specific example to follow, basically, we targeting as a subfolder, GB, US, CA, AU, NZ, IE. Is the same site for all and only English. Means will be the same route and content for all those subdirectories.

mysite.com/country/page-1

On which area we should set the country and subdirectory and also the big thing how this will work with express and angular Universal as SSR.

Our site is hosted on Azure + IIS

I'll appreciate all your help.
Thx

Server.ts

```
                import 'zone.js/dist/zone-node';

                import * as express from 'express';
                import {join} from 'path';

                import { environment } from './src/environments/environment';

                // Express server
                const app = express();

                const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8080;
                const DIST_FOLDER = join(process.cwd(), 'dist');
                console.log('processPath',process.cwd());

                // * NOTE :: leave this as require() since this file is built Dynamically from webpack
                const {AppServerModuleNgFactory, LAZY_MODULE_MAP, ngExpressEngine, provideModuleMap, RESPONSE, REQUEST} = require('./dist/server/main');


                app.set('view engine', 'html');
                app.set('views', join(DIST_FOLDER, 'project'));

                // Start up the Node server
                app.listen(PORT, () => {
                console.log(`Node Express server listening on http://localhost:${PORT}`);
                });

                app.set('case sensitive routing', true);

                import lowercasePaths from 'express-lowercase-paths';
                app.use(lowercasePaths());

                // https://github.com/expressjs/express/issues/2727
                app.use(function(req,res,next){
                req.connection.setNoDelay(true);
                next();
                });


                // /* https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware.html */
                const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
                app.use(bodyParser.json({ type: 'application/*+json' }));
                app.use(bodyParser.text({ type: 'text/html' }));
                app.use(express.json());


                /* https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/serve-static.html */
                app.use(express.static(join(DIST_FOLDER, 'project'), { maxAge: '4 days', redirect: false }));

                app.use(function (req, res, next) { next(); });

                // Server static files from /project
                // TODO: check if this is needed, the maxAge value is not being applied, it is using line 122 above
                app.get('*.*', express.static(join(DIST_FOLDER, 'project'), {
                maxAge: '4 days',
                redirect: false
                }));

                // TODO: implement data requests securely
                app.get('/api/*', (req, res) => {
                res.status(404).send('data requests are not supported');
                });

                // Example Express Rest API endpoints
                // app.get('/api/**', (req, res) => { });

                // All regular routes use the Universal engine
                app.get('*', (req, res) => {
                res.render('index', { req });
                });

                /*
                How to make an Angular app witch Universal SSR use dynamic configurations from json file?
                https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55704526/how-to-make-an-angular-app-witch-universal-ssr-use-dynamic-configurations-from-j
                */
                app.engine('html', (_, options, callback) => {
                const protocol = options.req.protocol;
                const host = options.req.get('host');

                const engine = ngExpressEngine({
                    bootstrap: AppServerModuleNgFactory,
                    providers: [
                    provideModuleMap(LAZY_MODULE_MAP),
                    { provide: 'BASE_URL', useFactory: () => `https://${host}`, deps: [] },
                    { provide: 'REQ_HEADERS', useFactory: () => JSON.stringify(options.req.headers), deps: []},
                    {
                        provide: REQUEST,
                        useValue: options.req,
                        /* https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52668630/angular-6-server-side-rendering-ssr-set-status-code-from-component */
                    },
                    {
                        provide: RESPONSE,
                        useValue: options.req.res,
                    },
                    ]
                });
                engine(_, options, callback);
                });
```

Comment: Share your `server.ts` file

Comment: server.ts attached

Comment: I am unable to understand what exactly you are looking for? Is country added to URL irrespective of locale? What is your determinant to identify the locale?

Comment: I'm looking to the have server-side render project, that load the same project on different subdirectories,

Comment: I'm looking to load my angular universal app, as a dynamic subdirectory or basehref, so when a request is made like, www.mysite.com/us/  - the /us will be injected on the base href HTML in angular or by expressjs and then load the app. Then if another user tries to load www.mysite.com/uk, take /uk replace the base href in the HTML and the load the app -- 

Is the same app, same content, the only difference is a currency between the 2 locations URLs, all this to avoid duplication on the app or project